# Strtotime function that will work in ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, strtotime

I'm trying to concatenate date and time values from multiple select boxes using strtotime in php, however, I need to have this converted timestamp variable in my ajax call.

The Code:

```
    <form>
    <select id="month">
        <option value="1">January</option>
    </select>
    <select id="day">
        <option value="22">22</option>
    </select>
    <select id="year">
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
    </select>
    <select id="time">
        <option value="12:00:00">12:00</option>
    </select>
    <button id="submitNow">
</form>

$("#submitNow").click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();

        var timestamp = /*need to basically do strtotime($month . "-" . $day . "-" . $year . " " .  $time) */

        var promises = [];
        var promise;


        $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
            $.ajax({
               type:'POST',
               url:'url/test',
               data:{timestamp:timestamp},
               _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
               success:function(data){  
                  window.location.href = "/library";
               }
          });
    });
});
```

So basically, in PHP I can dump `strtotime($month . "-" . $day . "-" . $year . " " .  $time)` and get the unix timestamp for 1-22-2020 12:00:00 but I need to do this in a way (in laravel) so that I can submit the timestamp (1548158400) in my ajax call

What's the best way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blade is still just a php file (name.blade.php), so you should be able to do this.

```
var timestamp = <?php echo strtotime($month . "-" . $day . "-" . $year . " " .  $time); ?>
```

Comment: ah ok, so just set the JS var to the php function. I didn't think about that, thanks!

Comment: Wait, I just realized: The php syntax won't work if I don't have those php variables. I made js variables ```var year = document.getElementById("selectYear").value;
        var month = document.getElementById("selectMonth").value;
        var day = document.getElementById("selectDay").value;
        var time = document.getElementById("selectTime").value;``` so how would I run the php function on that?

Comment: in that case, why don't you pass the js vars to data and build the timestamp in url/test ?